# Set missing date time in R

Tags: r, date, time

I have a list of dates with time like this:

```
 x
"2013-10-23T10:00"
"2013-10-23T10:09" 
"2013-10-23T00:00"
"2013-10-23"
```

I would like to set missing times so it looka like this:

```
x
"2013-10-23 10:00:00"
"2013-10-23 10:09:00" 
"2013-10-23 23:59:59"
"2013-10-23 23:59:59"
```

I've tried this but it doesn't quite work. Is there a way to do it?

```
as.POSIXct(x, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
x = Sys.time()
library(lubridate)
x + hours(23) + minutes(59) + (59)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c("2013-10-23T10:00", "2013-10-23T10:09", "2013-10-23T00:00", "2013-10-23")
x[nchar(x) == 10] <- paste0(x[nchar(x) == 10], 'T23:59:59')
x[nchar(x) == 16] <- paste0(x[nchar(x) == 16], ':00')
x <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
x
```